# DateAdd and Datediff function in C#

Tags: c#

I just want to ask if C# has the `DateAdd` and `Datediff` functions like in VB.Net? If yes, can you give sample code, if you all don't mind?

I tried `DateTime.Today.AddDays()` but it could not satisfy my needs for the program. What I want is to add 3 days to the date of transaction and when that date comes, the program will compare it with the system date of the computer and if they are equal, it means that transaction is overdue.

Here's my simple code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dtenow;

    dtenow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3);
    MessageBox.Show("" + dtenow);

    if (dtenow >= DateTime.Now)
        MessageBox.Show("Overdue");
}
```

Please help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Subtracting one date from another gives you a [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8). Why won't `DateTime.Today.AddDays(3)` work?

Comment: overdue should be when `DateTime.Today.AddDays(3) < DateTime.Now`. Calculated time should be less than now.

Comment: actually this program part is for hotel reservation, if someone reserves for a check-in schedule, the hotel will record the date of reservation their client wants and they will give their client 3 days grace period to confirm their reservation, if 3 days had passed, then that schedule will be cancelled and will be open to other customer